# Align multiple images (with captions) to baseline, all different heights

Tags: jquery, css, image, baseline

I've been searching for days how to get this layout working, I need a little help

I just want my images to be aligned to the baseline of the tallest image, per line, and the captions below that line. I see you have a lot of experience with building layouts with images and jquery, If you could point me in the right direction I think I could solve it.

Here is the jsfiddle for what Ive got, but I think I might have to ditch masonry as my client just wants a nice baseline.. but with a responsive wrap of course..
http://jsfiddle.net/perrodeagua/SeXDu/embedded/result/

Here's my current css, I ain't married to it though

```
.thePics {
padding:5px;
font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 24px;
float: left;
 width:200px;
 height:auto;
 border:1px;
 text-align:left;


}

#PICS {
 width:auto;
}
```

And here is mockup of what I need
http://postimg.org/image/sygkducs5/

Thanks!

Comment: Can you set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Jsfiddle please... So CSS and HTML.

Comment: use service like lorempixel.com, dummyimage.com or placehold.it for images in your jsfiddle.

Comment: what you are asking is default behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/fxn64/ We will be needing some of you code to help (no need for the actual images, any image will work, as you can see in the fiddle)

Comment: @PeterVR: That is true, but only if you have one single baseline for all the images - which you don't, if you have captions underneath them.

Comment: You guys rock! What a nice community! OK so here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/perrodeagua/SeXDu/

I am using masonry and phpthumb.. al images are 200px wide with variable height.. but all of this can change what i need most is the baseline, and the responsive wrap of the main container..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your captions are all of uneven lengths as well, then Flexbox is your best pure CSS option.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/vJeDk

```
<div class="gallery">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x200" />
    <figcaption>My caption here, this one is a really long one. Oh boy, so long.</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150" />
    <figcaption>My caption here</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.gallery {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: baseline;
  -webkit-align-items: baseline;
  align-items: baseline;
  -webkit-box-align: baseline;
  -moz-box-align: baseline;
}

.gallery figure {
  /* optional */
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

/* optional */
.gallery {
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

If your elements need to wrap, then browser support is limited to Opera, Chrome, and IE10.  http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Comment: What is this flexbox magik you speak of? Pretty cool! I'm trying to get the <figcaption> element to stay at 200px width and I'm good to go! I hope.. I would definitely need support for safari though! let me check out if its possible. You people are awesome by the way!

Comment: Neither the  <figure> nor the  <figcaption> seem to accept width:200px;  :(

Comment: The flex/box-flex property is causing the width to be ignored.  Just drop it and it will work.  As long as you don't need wrapping, Safari is supported.

Comment: I just never understood why you included the flex box code in the figure element, the code that says /* optional */, it works better without that. Anyway its working perfect, thanks!

Comment: I don't have a way to test in iOS, but it does work in Safari 5 for Windows.

Comment: is it possible to have the images aligned to the top, but have the captions aligned with each other?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  Not if the images are all irregularly sized.

Answer (score 2):

You mean, like this? http://jsfiddle.net/LeBen/yFEc6/

[image: Expected result]

Actually tested in Chrome, Safari & Firefox and images are aligned to the baseline by default using `<figure>`.

Comment: comic sans and kittens... Al we miss now is the rainbows!

Comment: This is the cutest answer I've seen all day.

Comment: This works fine as long as the captions have the same number of lines:  http://jsfiddle.net/yFEc6/1/

Comment: In this case I would suggest truncating it but it might not fit the needs http://jsfiddle.net/LeBen/yFEc6/4/

Comment: Also, it's preferred that you paste the code into your answer as well.  Never know when jsfiddle will go down (which happens fairly often).

Comment: Here is what i have now, using masonry and phpthumb
http://postimg.org/image/gi744v10z/

Comment: I do need variable caption size. they can actually be quite big, I've never heard of the <figure> element, but I think it might work with some tweaking. Let me wotk on it, thanks a lot btw!

Comment: Then you should remove masonry as you try to do exactly the opposite of why it was designed for.

Comment: Indeed, goodbye masonry, hello figure element, also hello Flexbox.. nice to meet you.

Comment: still . i find it hard to believe that this is not something jquery or vanilla javascript could handle easily.. personally i would love a mod for masonry that actually forced divs to float all the way left and not get stuck midway! Anyway <figure> is a nice adition to html I didn't know about. Anyway if i ever figure out how to do it with jquery I'll come back here and post it. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT --**
 Le Ben's answer is cooler than mine if you can use HTML5, but if you need to support IE 8, this should work

If your images are aligning like this:

```
---- ---- ----
|  | |  | |  |
---- |  | ----
     ----
```

And you want them like this:

```
     ----
---- |  | ----
|  | |  | |  |
---- ---- ----
```

Just use some CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .captioned-img { display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom; }
    .caption       { text-align: center; }
</style>

<div class="captioned-img">
    <img />
    <p class="caption">Fig 1</p>
</div>
<div class="captioned-img">
    <img />
    <p class="caption">Fig 2</p>
</div>
<div class="captioned-img">
    <img />
    <p class="caption">Fig 3</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YTaVr/

Comment: Now it is an exact copy of LeBen's solution.

Comment: it's an answer to the problem, but unlike LeBen's solution, this one works for IE 8.  If you can't rely on HTML 5, you have to do something like this

Comment: The elements are irrelevant in this instance because the question is about the CSS (or potentially JavaScript).  All you did is copy LeBen's CSS and change the HTML elements.  You didn't even bother changing the HTML in the demo.

Comment: i did that on purpose, so they're easy to compare -- elements are absolutely relevant. try running LeBen's answer in IE 8 -- it doesn't work.  mine does.

Comment: OK.  I actually went to the trouble of jsfiddling your code, just here it is. http://jsfiddle.net/perrodeagua/xgQSC/ 
it obviusly doesnt work with variable lines in the caption div..