# Align thumbnail Images with different sizes, and with caption, at bottom

Tags: html, css, image

I have a simple thumbnail with images and a caption for each image. The images do not have the same height but are always 125px.
Captions can be short and long, they do not have the same height.

I want to align all of the images at the bottom so i can put the caption at the same level.

Did some research here and was able to align the images at the bottom, but without the caption

https://jsfiddle.net/0bzz7397/2/

```
.thumb {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.thumb > div {
  flex: 0 0 125px;
  background-color: white;
}

.thumb > div ~ div {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

When i add the caption, well, it's a MESS!

https://jsfiddle.net/fuk45osb/1/

**EDIT:**
i've included an example with multiple wrapped thumbs

https://jsfiddle.net/fuk45osb/5/

Basically, this is the effect i'm hoping for. Images with different height are all aligned at the bottom, and the caption starts at the same level. It's simple and clean.

[image: images are all aligned at the bottom]

[image]

Ive try using flexbox. But, maybe i'm wrong and there are better ways.

Any ideas how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

In this very limited scenario I'd use absolute positioning for title and subtitle.

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.thumb {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.thumb>div {
  flex: 0 0 125px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.thumb>div~div {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumb">
  <div>
    <a href=""><img src="" width="125" height="125"></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href=""><img src="" width="125" height="170"></a>
    <div class="title">wefweergergerg erg er erg erg erg er gfwef</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href=""><img src="" width="125" height="125"></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href=""><img src="" width="125" height="130"></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href=""><img src="" width="125" height="160"></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href=""><img src="" width="125" height="125"></a>
    <div class="title">wefwefwef</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href=""><img src="" width="125" height="125"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is helpful, unfortunately, when the thumbs are wrapped, they are on top of each other see https://jsfiddle.net/fuk45osb/4/

Comment: @Marco well, how did you envision it would work? :) Maybe you should have included that in your question.

Comment: @Marco you added an example of how it currently stacks. I'm curious how you imagine it should stack.

Comment: ok, i get what you're saying. I've added an image to show how they should stack

Answer (score 1):

I kept researching a couple of more hours here and found an answer, for those who are interested.

The answer comes from this very similar post created years ago:

[Align multiple images (with captions) to baseline, all different heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926505/align-multiple-images-with-captions-to-baseline-all-different-heights?rq=1)

Basically, you just need to change the attribute `align-items` from `flex-end` to `baseline`. As simple as that.

Here's a working example
https://jsfiddle.net/fuk45osb/7/